# /civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Case/BAO/Query.php Reported to Contain Malware by Wordfence

Tags: civicase, security

I'm testing Wordfence a WordPress security plug-in on our site.  It reports that /civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Case/BAO/Query.php contains suspected malware.  Is this true? We are running CiviCRM 4.7.2.

Here's the Wordfence message:

[image: Wordfence Scan Result]

Answer (score 1):

No, this is a false positive.

The line flagging this is:

> $from .= " $side JOIN civicrm_option_value recent_activity_medium ON
>   (case_activity.medium_id = recent_activity_medium.value AND
>   option_group_activity_**medium.id** =
>   recent_activity_medium.option_group_id ) ";

Suggested courses of action:
1. Get rid of Wordfence.
2. Tell Wordfence about this false positive and request they fix it.

Comment: Wordfence is a pretty decent and widely-used plugin for WordPress. A gentler course of action to suggest for George would have been to click "I have fixed this issue" link, and dismiss the notice.

Comment: Or that :) - Stack Exchange doesn't just let me type "Or that :)"

Comment: The false positives cleared themselves up with no action on my part.  Maybe the first scan had a glitch and the later scan ran OK.